# recyclerview.onBindviewholder always in position 0

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

`recyclerview.onbindviewholder` always in position 0

```
public class NoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public static final int UNCOMPLETED = 0;
    public static final int COMPLETED = 1;
    public static final int HIGHTLIGHT = 2;
    public static final int HIGHTLIGHT_COMPETED = 3;
    Cursor cursor;
    Context context;

    public NoteAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    public Cursor getCursor() {
        return this.cursor;
    }

    public void setCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            cursor.move(position);
            String content = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_CONTENT));
            int completed = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_COMPLETED));
            int hightlight = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_HIGHTLIGHT));


            if (completed == 1) {
                if (hightlight == 1) {
                    return HIGHTLIGHT_COMPETED;
                }
                return COMPLETED;
            }

            if (hightlight == 1 && completed == 0) {
                return HIGHTLIGHT;
            }

            return UNCOMPLETED;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);

        switch (viewType) {
            case UNCOMPLETED:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
                break;
            case COMPLETED:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row_completed, parent, false);
                break;
            case HIGHTLIGHT:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row_hightlight, parent, false);
                break;
            case HIGHTLIGHT_COMPETED:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row_hightlight_completed, parent, false);
                break;
        }

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (!cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return;
        }
        String content = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_CONTENT));
        Date date = Utilities.stringToDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_DEADLINE)));

        int completed = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_COMPLETED));

        holder.tvContent.setText(content);
        holder.tvDate.setText(Utilities.dateToString(date));

        if(completed == 1){
            holder.imgIcon.performClick();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (cursor.getCount());
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvContent;
        TextView tvDate;
        ImageButton imgIcon;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
            tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
            imgIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgCheck);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    cursor.move(position);

                    Note note = Utilities.cursorToNote(cursor);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), AddNoteActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtras(note.sendNoteBundle());
                    intent.putExtra("type", true);
                    itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The program does not contain any errors.
When I run the program, it always only shows the element at the 0 position, the remaining positions do not show.

function `getItemCount` works normally, returning 20 elements.

English is not my native language, sorry for any grammatical errors. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Hi Zeroes, Your conditions are not being satisfied. getItemViewType always return UNCOMPLETED.

Comment: thank answers. but getItemViewType is correct, i try print Logd in getItemViewType and position always equals 0.  And in postion 0, getItemViewTy return HIGHTLIGHT.

Comment: Thanks edited Touhidul Islam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the `android:layout_height` for your parent layout in the layout(xml) files for the various ViewHolders has been set to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.

Comment: Thanks Networks.cursor.move(position); and layout_height = "match_parent". thank you very much.

Comment: @Zeroes I face the same problem. how exactly you solved your problem?

Comment: @KaavehMohamedi change layout_height from "match_parent" to "wrap_content"